# Separate class for each variable in proc means

Tags: sas

I need to do a sum on various variables at once. Further, for each variabled, yi summed there is a class variable linked, xi.

The code should look something like this:

```
proc means data=test sum;
class x1-x100;
var y1-y100;
run;
```

Instead of having class x1 for var y1, this uses x1-x100 as class for var y1, same for y2,..., y100.
How do I write it, such that var y1 has class x1, var y2 has class x2 and so on?
My output should be in one big table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just transpose the data so that instead of 100 pairs of variables you have one pair of variables and 100 rows?  Let's make some sample data:

```
data have ;
  input x1-x2 y1-y2 ;
cards;
1 1 3 4
1 2 5 6
2 1 7 8
2 2 9 0
;
```

Now transpose it by turning the X's into `CLASS` variable and the Y's into `VALUE` variable.  We will use `INDEX` to note which of the many class/value pairs this observation represents.

```
data tall ;
  set have ;
  array x x1-x2;
  array y y1-y2;
  do index=1 to dim(x);
     class=x(index);
     value=y(index);
     output;
  end;
run;
```

Now we just using `PROC SUMMARY` (aka PROC MEANS) to calculate the sum.

```
proc summary nway;
  class index class ;
  var value;
  output out=want sum=sum;
run;
```

And we can print the result:

```
proc print ;
  var index class sum ;
run;

  index    class    sum
    1        1        8
    1        2       16
    2        1       12
    2        2        6
```

You could also do the transpose AFTER the PROC SUMMARY, assuming that the number of combinations does not exceed the amount of memory available.

First run the PROC SUMMARY using `WAYS 1` to limit the number of class variables used. Use `CHARTYPE` to allow so many class variables at once.  To get the results to appear in the order X1,X2,...X100 reference the variables in the `CLASS` and `VAR` statement in the opposite order.

```
proc summary data=have chartype ;
  class x2-x1;
  ways 1;
  var y2-y1;
  output out=step1 sum= ;
run;
```

Now take the result and use the `_TYPE_` variable to match the class variable with the proper sum variable.

```
data want ; 
  length class_name sum_name $32 ;
  set step1 ;
  array x x2-x1 ;
  array y y2-y1 ;
  i=indexc(_type_,'1') ;
  class_name = vname(x(i));
  sum_name=vname(y(i));
  class=x(i);
  sum=y(i);
  drop _type_ i x: y: ;
run;
```

Results:

```
class_
name     sum_name    _FREQ_    class    sum
 x1         y1          2        1        8
 x1         y1          2        2       16
 x2         y2          2        1       12
 x2         y2          2        2        6
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like PROC TABULATE to me.

```
data have;
  array x[100];
  array y[100];
  do _n_ = 1 to 1e4;
    do _i = 1 to 100;
      x[_i] = rand('BINOMIAL',.3,3);
      y[_i] = rand('UNIFORM');
    end;
    output;
  end;
run;


proc tabulate data=have;
  class x1-x100;
  var y1-y100;
  tables
     x1*y1=' '
     x2*y2=' '
     x100*y100=' ',sum;
run;
```

Use a macro loop to populate the full list of course.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use call execute.

**Modification:**

```
data _null_;
   set have(obs=1);
   array x x:;
   array y y:;
   do i=1 to dim(x);
      call execute(
      'proc means nway data=have sum;
          class x'||strip(i)||';
          var y'||strip(i)||';
          output out=temp sum=;
      run;');
     if i=1 then call execute(
           'data want;
            set temp(drop=_:);
         run;');
     else call execute(
          'data want;
          merge want temp(drop=_:);
        run;');
     end;
  run;
```

Comment: Did OP say that  results should be stored in one file? If yes, then modify it.

Comment: OP final sentence is `My output should be in one big table.`

Comment: Ok, good, I have modified, I also need to see doctor to check my eyes.

Answer (score 0):

In case it's useful, here's an option that's a combination of Tom's and Joe's solutions.  Proc tabulate to create a printable report and an output dataset.  Then process the output dataset from proc tab to combine things as desired.

```
data have ;
  input x1-x3 y1-y3 ;
cards;
1 1 3 4 5 6
1 2 5 6 7 8
2 1 7 8 9 10
2 2 9 0 11 12
;


%macro x_by_y;

    proc tabulate data=have
                    out=table_out(keep=x: y: _type_)
                    noseps
                    format=comma10.0;

        class x1-x3;
        var y1-y3;

        table
            %do i = 1 %to 3;
                x&i.*y&i.=' '
            %end;
            , sum;
    run;

    data table2(keep=classvar ysum);
        set table_out;
        array ysums[*] y:;

        x_index=indexc(_type_, '1');
        classvar= compress('x' || x_index);
        ysum = max(of ysums[*]);
    run;

    proc print data=table2 noobs;
    run;
%mend x_by_y;

%x_by_y;
```